# Isomorphism of Archimedean real closed fields with infinite transcendence degree

Tags: fields

Are all countable Archimedean real closed fields with infinite transcendence degree isomorphic?

Comment: No, just take a proper inclusion between two such subfields of $\mathbf{R}$. (The only possible isomorphism would be the identity.)

Comment: Thank you very much!